# How to know how many object (for instance button or textview) there are in a layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

Is there a way to know how many object of a certain kind (textview or button orimageview etc) there are in a layout. Of course there is a way, but I don't know how to start.

Comment: you mean direct children or recursively in the whole sub-hierarchy ?

Comment: Aren't you creating those..?

Comment: I mean direct children,
Actually i want to manage those object. For example, i woubld like to set the background of the imageviews that there are in a layout. So i need to know how many imageviews there are, then i need to "get"  them without knowing their names; i need to identify them dinamically.

Comment: out of curiosity, why do you need that?

Comment: because i want to manage all certain kind of object in a layout, without knowing how many they are. I don't want to do this

 `TextView t1= (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
t1.setText("bla");`
Because i might have 50 textview!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using the following recursive method:

```
public int getChildrenCount(ViewGroup parent, Class type) {
    int count = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<parent.getChildCount(); i++) {
        View child = parent.getChildAt(i);

        if(child instanceof ViewGroup) {
            count += getChildrenCount((ViewGroup) child, type);
        }
        else {
            if(child.getClass() == type) {
                // Try to find element name in XML layout
                for(Field field : R.id.class.getDeclaredFields()) {
                    try {
                        int id = field.getInt(null);
                        if(id == child.getId()) {
                            String childName = field.getName();
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // error handling
                    }
                }
                //

                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

For instance, to find all the `TextView` children in the `activity_main` layout:

```
    ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);        
    int count = getChildrenCount(parent, TextView.class);
```

Comment: Is there a way to identify the name of object? For example, when i set `android:id="@+id/objectname"` in the xml, how can i get that id?
I tried to edit your code writing `if(child.getClass() == type){ count++;
String name= child.getId();}`
 but it doesne't work

Comment: Finding the string ID defined in the XML file is not really obvious. But it's possible, see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

You can find out by using [getChildCount()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#getChildCount%28%29) and [getChildAt()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#getChildAt%28int%29)

For example:

```
    RelativeLayout fl = new RelativeLayout(this);
    int childCount = fl.getChildCount();
    int buttonCount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
        if(fl.getChildAt(i) instanceof Button){
            buttonCount++;
        }
    }
```

**Note: This Method checks only for direct Children/Descendants of the ViewGroup.**